# Passing value to new Date giving Invalid date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

When i pass value to new Date then i get Invalid date. I am doing it like

```
        var s1 = moment("20.06.2013 09:11:00", "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        var s2 = s1.format("YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm:ss");
        var dt1 = s2.replace(/[-,.:\s]/g, ",");
        var dt2 = new Date(dt1);
```

In Debug mode in google chrome when i get value of dt1 as "2013,06,20,09,11,00". But when i  type like `new Date(2013,06,20,09,11,34)` then i get date.

I also tried removing double quotes but it doesnt remove double quotes. What should i do to get rid of this error.

Comment: You're passing a single string — "2013,06,20,09,11,34" — to `new Date`, not multiple arguments.

Comment: @kalley how to do this then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are after a `Date`, but want to parse using moment.js, then just do this:

```
var m = moment("20.06.2013 09:11:00", "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss");
var dt = m.toDate();
```

Comment: This works. Is it possible to add GMT time to the output. I did like
var dt = m.toDate().getTime() and i get output as 1371712260000. I wwant output as 1371712260000+0200

Comment: You can use `m.valueOf() + m.format('ZZ')`  - but I'd question anywhere that expects that format.  Usually when an offset is paired with a value, it means the offset is *already* reflective of that value.  But a timestamp in seconds or millseconds is almost always just in UTC.  So these concerns are conflicting.

Comment: i want to pass json date format. That is why i need to add this +0200 otherwise i get time 2 hours back

Comment: Basically, you want this:  `m.utc().format("[/Date](XSSS") + m.local().format("ZZ)/")`.   Note that it would be *much* better to switch to the standard ISO8601 format.  Also note, it is specifically the "asp.net json date format".  JSON itself does not define a format for dates, so there is no such thing as *the* "json  date format".

Answer (score 0):

As Kalley suggested, use parameters in your code:

```
 var s1 = moment([2013,06,20,09,11,34]);
```

Edited to add:  In Jscript, moment() takes an array in the format [Y,M,D,h,m,s].  Source: http://momentjs.com/docs/